# Creating Hyperlink Dynamically in last row of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i tried to get values from database and display it in a Gridview like a table, the problem is , i wanted to make the last row, which is the File Row to become a hyperlink that can redirect to other webforms. I tried using the code below and it couldn't work, any clue on how to dynamically add a hyperlink? i do not want it to be tag of  etc, as i would not know how many datas will be in a database, Thanks in advance.

```
sqlDr = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Extension", typeof(string));
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("File", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add(dc);
dataTable.Columns.Add(dc1);
dataTable.Columns.Add(dc2);
dataTable.Columns.Add(dc3);

//here
while (sqlDr.Read())
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = sqlDr["DOCID"].ToString();
    dr["Name"] = sqlDr["FILENAME"].ToString();
    dr["Extension"] = sqlDr["GENERATEDDOCID"].ToString();

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.ID = sqlDr["DOCID"].ToString();
        link.NavigateUrl = "members.aspx?showLease=";
        e.Row.Cells.Add(link);
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}

downloadFilesTable.DataSource = dataTable;
downloadFilesTable.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. Loop each cell of the last row in the GridView and add a HyperLink.

```
foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count -1].Cells)
{
    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
    hl.NavigateUrl = "members.aspx?showLease=" + cell.Text;
    hl.Text = cell.Text;
    cell.Controls.Add(hl);
}
```

Or you can make the entire row clickable with JavaScript.

```
GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.href='/members.aspx?showLease='");
GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to modify the code and add it into every last column in the gridview row? Thanks @VDWWD

Comment: If you want it in every row, a TemplateField would be much easier. You can then add a HyperLink in that TemplateField.